MySQL regular expression query to check if string is contained outside brackets
I want a regular expression which I can use on MySQL.

The string I'm looking for must be contained outside the brackets.
brackets don't have nesting.(if exists, I don't care result)
brackets have beginning and ending.(if not, I don't care result)

Let be "3" the word I'm looking for. This changes every time.
This table is a part of result I want.



-
target string
result




1
[123]
not match


2
123
match


3
[123]123
match


4

not match


5
[123][123]
not match


6
[123]123[123]
match


7
[[123]]
not exist (nesting)


8
123[123
not exist (no ending)



Below is the query to create the table: (sqlfiddle)
create table my_table(id integer,text varchar(128));
insert into my_table(id,text) values 
(1,"[123]"),
(2,"123"),
(3,"[123]123"),
(4,""),
(5,"[123][123]"),
(6,"[123]123[123]"),
(7,"[[123]]"),
(8,"123[123");


select * from my_table where text REGEXP "3";

This select query returns 1,2,3,5,6,7,8.
But 1 and 5 should not be returned.

"I want" is no question. Please show what you have tried and explain what exactly doesn't work as expected.

@jonas-metzler I have a few knowledge about regex, but I couldn't find anything more meaningful than the last select query.

For some reason I can't edit the question so I'll write it here, the last query excludes #4 but doesn't exclude #1 and #5.

#5 does not match whereas #6 matches. Why?

You can probably use ...WHERE text REGEXP '3[^\\]]*(\\[|$)';

Since you're effectively ignoring whatever is inside square brackets, you can match zero to many square-bracketed strings interleaved with optional non-bracket characters, before and after the actual string you want to match:
select * from my_table where text REGEXP
"^[^\\[\\]]*(\\[[^\\]]*][^\\[\\]]*)*3[^\\[\\]]*(\\[[^\\]]*][^\\[\\]]*)*$";

This outputs:
2   123
3   [123]123
6   [123]123[123]

Demo: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=1d56cbf0-6472-4d3b-a6d0-b26932e35251

Here's the trick, I used subquery to remove all those fields with valid [text] format, then applied a filter.
select t.*,  t1.res, case
    when locate(']', t1.res)  = 1 then 'not exist (nesting)' 
    when locate('[', t1.res)  > 1 then 'not exist (no ending)'
    when ifnull(t1.res, '') = '' then 'not match'
    else 'matched' end as result
from
my_table t
left join (
    select id, regexp_replace(text, '\\[[^]]*\\]', '') res
    from my_table) t1 on t.id = t1.id
where t.text REGEXP '3';


This can result in false positives if the OP is looking for a multi-character word. For example, if the OP is looking for 23, then with your code 2[]3 will incorrectly match.
